# Save encoded .mp3 to applicationStorageDirectory Adobe Air iOS

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I'm developing an iOS iPad app w/ Flash CS5.5 AIR v.3.1

I'm using ShineMp3Encoder to encode a Wav to a Mp3 from:
https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy

Basically it converts a byteArray (wav) to a byteArray (mp3) or "mp3encoder.mp3Data" in the code.

I have no trouble saving this using a (new FileReference()).save(mp3Data, filename); but because this is being used in a iOS AIR app I wanted to switch to using the File.applicationStorageDirectory so that I could put the saved mp3 into it's own folder to keep organized.  When I run the code it goes through all the steps, converts the wav to mp3, and then says that it saves but doesn't with no errors.  The sound IS stored in memory, as it is able to be played back until the app is closed.  I've changed the resolvePath to the root folder, myApp/, and to /sounds - None of which work.  I've never attempted to do this before so I'm a little lost why no file is being created.  Anyone with any suggestions would help a lot.

```
function onEncoded(e:Event):void{
    myTI.text = "Mp3 encoded and saved. Press Play.";
    mp3encoder.mp3Data.position = 0;
    var myDate:Date = new Date();
    var theDate:String = myDate.monthUTC.toString() + myDate.dayUTC.toString() 
        + myDate.hoursUTC.toString() + myDate.minutesUTC.toString() 
        + myDate.secondsUTC.toString();

    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/sounds/myVoice+"+theDate+".mp3");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream;
    fileStream.open(file,FileMode.UPDATE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(mp3encoder.mp3Data);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but try this. If it works, modify the filename to be dynamic as you require.

```
var myfilename:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
myfilename = myfilename.resolvePath("myVoice.mp3");


var outputStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
outputStream.open(myfilename,FileMode.WRITE);
outputStream.writeBytes(mp3encoder.mp3Data,0,mp3encoder.mp3Data.length);
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: This produced the same result.  It runs all the way through the code with no errors, and with no result.

Comment: How are you testing to see if the file has been written?

Comment: I'm testing on my computer, so I've just been checking in the folder that contains my .fla .swf etc. for any .mp3 or temp file.  I figure if it doesn't work here it isn't going to work once converted.

Everything behaves the same once converted to an .ipa and installed on the iPad so I'd like to get it working on my computer before getting too ahead of myself.  It SHOULD work both ways once it works on one...

Comment: Lots of things 'should' work but as I've found that's not always the case. Are you using a Mac and do you have Xcode installed as they make it easier to see whether files are being stored on the device.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunately true...

I'm using a PC..  I do have access to a Mac that's registered w/ another developer that has xCode that I could probably borrow

Comment: so I just changed to .documentsDirectory and .userDirectory and both of these save the file...in different locations.  After a little more research it looks like this might be the place I'd want to save these files as they won't be overwritten and will be backed up with a iPad sync.

Comment: So are you sorted now? FYI once your app is installed on the iPad and you have saved a file, connect it to the Mac, Launch XCode, open the organiser window and select the iPad from the devices list. You should then be able to select your app and see what files are contained within it's sandbox.

Comment: I wasn't able to view the app with xCode...  My other solution is to just search for the file and play it back but I'm not sure how to find the file...  I think I'm looking for something similar to this:  function testPlay (event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var snd:Sound = new Sound();
 snd.load(new URLRequest(File.documentsDirectory+"myVoice.mp3"));
 snd.play();
}

Comment: For anyone interested here's what I got to work.


function testPlay (event:MouseEvent):void
{
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myVoice.mp3"); 
var trade:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.url)
var snd:Sound = new Sound(trade);
snd.play();
}

Comment: @user1129107 If you open outputStream with  FileMode.WRITE or APPEND, the directories are created for you. If you use UPDATE, the directories must already exist. Call ...resolvePath("myApp/sounds").createDirectory()

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is little bit late, but maybe it will be useful for somebody who will find this post in future.

When you develop on Windows in Adobe AIR and try to save something in File.applicationStorageDirectory it will NOT saved in the same folder like your swf or fla file.

It will be saved here:
C:\Users[WIN_LOGIN]\AppData\Roaming[APP_ID]\Local Store

Your APP_ID you will find and set in Publish Settings for IOS.